# How to know multiple versions of java are installed on windows machine

Tags: java

I have multiple version of java on my windows once  I check it using following command

java -version

It shows me only 1.8 version even though I have installed java 6 and java 7.

Comment: `dir %programfiles%\java*`?

Comment: Actually I want to see all those versions on command prompt .

Comment: This is just a guess, but that might be simply the version your system defaults to which is the most current version. I don't think that java -version can return more than a single value. So while you might have a few different versions on your hard drive, only one is being used by your OS when the JRE is called.

Comment: yes Glen , At a time OS can use only one JRE and java -version also shows only one version . So it might be showing me only latest version of java. Anyways Thank you.

Comment: Only one of your java installations is coupled to the command `java`. It is set in Windows `PATH` variable and it will use the first `java.exe` it encounters while scanning the listed directories. So you will need to manually search your directories and use the command with **full path** to the `exe` instead. Alternatively setup a proper IDE like eclipse, it can easily handle multiple Java installations. Also note that you don't need to install other versions, they are backwards compatible and can be run in older versions mode. Again an IDE can do this with 2 simple clicks in the settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using command prompt you can see only default installation of Java.  I. E.  Which is set in system environment variables. 
But using registry you can see all the installed version of Java. 
Follow following instructions..

On Windows, it looks like all of the installations are recorded in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/JavaSoft/Java Runtime Environment registry key.

Comment: this isn't the thing now, because newer JDKs don't have a JRE, so you can't find them to that registry path.